# Batch file - Stopping services except for listed

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I remote into a computers and drop a few files in to repair the computer. I have a batch file that stops all running programs except for those contained in the batch file.

I would like another to go though each services and stop it EXCEPT for a few in the batch file making a virtual safe mode. I would like it to skip the service if it isn't running. (and echo if it is running or not)
I will have to run it a few time to stop dependencies but I will do that manually as needed. I have a similar program that uses an external text files for services to leave running, but would like to have a single files with the services contained within the batch file the the code below.

Can anyone scratch this out for me? I really appreciate it!

```
(Thanks to  Bharat)
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="explorer.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
echo.
taskkill /f /im "%%i" 
echo.
)
)
)
)
)
```

Comment: First, what have you tried so far? Second, any reason you aren't using powershell? This would be **way easier** that way.

Answer (score 0):

I completed My script with more research. I know it is ugly but it allows me to run on a remote computer, plus room for growth. It has a built in ignore list, deletes temp files and opens folders to confirm all other areas are empty.
Why Not powershell? I know less about that then Windows command. Just wanted to share and get any improvement.

```
@echo off
title Kill all running apps
color 0A
:start

cd c:\windows\System32
for /f "skip=3 tokens=1" %%i in ('TASKLIST /FI "USERNAME eq             %userdomain%\%username%" /FI "STATUS eq running"') do (
echo %%i
if not "%%i"=="svchost.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="explorer.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tasklist.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="notepad.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="dllhost.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cis.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cistray.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="taskmgr.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="conhost.exe" (
::desktop windows manager
if not "%%i"=="dwm.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tv_w32.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="tv_x64.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="TeamViewer.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="taskmgr.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
if not "%%i"=="cmd.exe" (
echo.
echo %%i
ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul
taskkill /f /im "%%i"
ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul
echo.
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)
)

:open
explorer.exe "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary     Internet Files\"
explorer.exe "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\"
explorer.exe %windir%\temp

:delete
echo.&echo.&Echo Now empty temp files.
::=========Delete temp files=========
::empty user temp folder
cd /d %temp%   
echo.&echo.&echo deleting files.......
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *

::empty Admin temp folder


echo.&echo.&echo Empty windows temp file
cd /d %windir%\temp\   
::dir /w
echo.&echo.&echo deleting files.......
for /d %%D in (*) do rd /s /q "%%D"
del /f /q *

goto folders


:folders
echo Now turn off processes
taskmgr
msconfig
Taskschd.msc
ping -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul

:eof
```